# Refactor Python script to a method, for integration with larger process

Tags: python, json, refactoring

What I need to do is refactor a script, to turn it into a method that can be added to a larger process.

**STEP A**

The point is- there's a data processing task that I'm working on- the first step is to create data of the following form:

```
3|Victoria|[51.503378, -0.139134]|2673
52|Cubitt Town|[51.505199, -0.018848]|23
5|United Kingdom|[54.75844, -2.69531]|459
6|London|[51.50853, -0.12574]|346
296|Bucharest|[44.43225, 26.10626]|9
352|Vilich-Müldorf|[50.75024, 7.15283]|4
48|Gut Scheibenhardt|[49.001249, 8.412378]|3
314|Westerham|[48.0601, 11.62219]|9
45|Honartsdeich|[53.557429, 9.987297]|34
9779|Martinsried|[48.137418, 11.555737]|11
343|Brussels|[50.85045, 4.34878]|27
563|Russell Square|[51.519403, -0.133906]|20
2|Germany|[51.5, 10.5]|20
11|Farringdon|[51.51807, -0.10852]|154
609|Fröttmaning|[48.16652, 11.59038]|3
```

**STEP B**

So then Step B will operate on the result of the above step (described by **PROCESS** below) and it will output data like so (the final data representation).

This means that **PROCESS** creates the data displayed in **STEP A**.

*The final data representation looks like this:*

```
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 2673
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 23
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 459
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 346
code: RO-B, jobs: 9
code: DE-NW, jobs: 4
code: DE-BW, jobs: 3
code: DE-BY, jobs: 9
code: DE-HH, jobs: 34
code: DE-BY, jobs: 11
code: BE-BRU, jobs: 27
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 20
code: DE-TH, jobs: 20
code: GB-ENG, jobs: 154
code: DE-BY, jobs: 3
```

The script which performs that magic (creates the final output data displayed above) looks in this way:

```
import json
import requests
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

# open up the output of 'data-processing.py'
with open('job-numbers-by-location.txt') as data_file:

    # print the output to a file
    with open('phase_ii_output.txt', 'w') as output_file_:
        for line in data_file:
            identifier, name, coords, number_of_jobs = line.split("|")
            coords = coords[1:-1]
            lat, lng = coords.split(",")
            # print("lat: " + lat, "lng: " + lng)
            response = requests.get("http://api.geonames.org/countrySubdivisionJSON?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&username=s.matthew.english").json()


            codes = response.get('codes', [])
            for code in codes:
                if code.get('type') == 'ISO3166-2':
                    country_code = '{}-{}'.format(response.get('countryCode', 'UNKNOWN'), code.get('code', 'UNKNOWN'))
                    if not hasNumbers( country_code ):
                        # print("code: " + country_code + ", jobs: " + number_of_jobs)
                        output_file_.write("code: " + country_code + ", jobs: " + number_of_jobs)
    output_file_.close()
```

But what I need to do is make it into a method, so I can fuse it into this process:

**PROCESS**

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint


def process_locations_data(data):
    # processes the 'data' block
    locations = defaultdict(int)
    for item in data['data']:
        location = item['relationships']['location']['data']['id']
        locations[location] += 1
    return locations


def process_locations_included(data):
    # processes the 'included' block
    return_list = []
    for record in data['included']:
        id = record.get('id', None)
        name = record.get('attributes', {}).get('name', None)
        coord = record.get('attributes', {}).get('coord', None)
        return_list.append((id, name, coord))
    return return_list    # return list of tuples




# load the data from file once
with open('data-science.txt') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


# use the two functions on same data
locations = process_locations_data(data)
records = process_locations_included(data)


# output list to collect lines
output = []


# combine the data for printing
for record in records:
    id, name, coord = record
    references = locations[id]   # lookup the references in the dict
    line = str(id) + "|" + str(name) + "|" + str(coord) + "|" + str(references) + "\n"
    if line not in output:
        output.append(line)


# print the output to a file
with open('job-numbers-by-location.txt', 'w') as file_:
    for l in output:
        if not ("None") in l:
            if not ("[0, 0]") in l:
                file_.write(l)
file_.close()
```

but the thing is- I keep failing in my efforts to make that script into a method within there.

How to refactorize that script into an independent method that could be included into the process?

All of the data related to this task can be found [here on my GitHub page](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/literate-octo-robot)

Comment: Have you tried defining the individual data as a class or set of classes? you can then compose classes or functions around that to load/create the data, and separately to print or save the data.

Comment: :/ what do you mean? I'm always writing programs that are "quick and dirty" so I don't have a good idea of software development.

Comment: you have a data file that you havent shown us that appears to contain a blob of json, which you then load as data. Instead of having everything i your script/program needing to know about the format/struicture of that json data, have you tried breaking it down, so you turn the json data into a ?list? of "Job" objects? Maybe with each job having a link to a "Location" object?

Comment: yeah- you're right about the json blob... that file is [here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/literate-octo-robot/blob/master/data_manipulation/data-science.txt), I haven't tried that, but I don't understand how it would improve the program- I'm kind of a novice

Comment: Depends what you mean by improve. You're the one that wants to refactor your a script into method. You could just indent the whole thing and put `def x():` at the top but that's probably not going to 'improve' it...

Comment: haha- nah man- you can't just do that. I already tried :) it gets all messy with the printing and data output- intermediary representations

Comment: I suspect that this is the best answer you're going to get. you might want to take a look at some object-oriented python tutorials which will hopefully better-explain the reasons why this approach might pay off in the long run. E.g. If your script had already been written this way to begin with, you probably wouldn't need to change it at all to use it from another module.